# how to combine results of query of multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, booleanquery

I have this results from this query.

```
select distinct "CVE_ID","V19_200","V20","V20_100","V21","V21_100","V21_200" 
from cve_table 
where "CVE_ID"='CVE-2022-22965';
```

| CVE_ID | V19_200 | V20 | V20_100 | V21 | V21_100 | V21_200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-2022-22965 | f | f | f | f | f | f |
| CVE-2022-22965 | f | f | f | f | t | f |
| CVE-2022-22965 | f | f | f | t | f | f |
| CVE-2022-22965 | f | f | t | f | f | f |
| CVE-2022-22965 | f | t | f | f | f | f |
| CVE-2022-22965 | t | f | f | f | f | f |

What I want is this.

| CVE_ID | V19_200 | V20 | V20_100 | V21 | V21_100 | V21_200 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-2022-22965 | t | t | t | t | t | f |

I have tried to `UNION` and `UNION ALL` but it didn't work for me or I couldn't do it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BOOL_OR` and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT "CVE_ID", 
       BOOL_OR("V19_200") as "V19_200", 
       BOOL_OR("V20") as "V20", 
       BOOL_OR("V20_100") as "V20_100", 
       BOOL_OR("V21") as "V21", 
       BOOL_OR("V21_100") as "V21_100", 
       BOOL_OR("V21_200") as "V21_200" 
FROM cve_table 
WHERE "CVE_ID" = 'CVE-2022-22965' 
GROUP BY "CVE_ID";
```

Comment: This did work great, exactly the way I needed in my question.